# Set limits within ggplot for ggrepel

Tags: r, ggplot2, limit, ggrepel

I have a ggplot graph with data similar to this:

```
data <- data.frame(x = c(1:30),
                   y = rnorm(30, 0, 1),
                   z = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 10))

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y, group = z, color = z, label = z)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = z), force = 1, segment.alpha = .5, box.padding = 1, xlim = c(-5, 35), ylim = c(-5, 5)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-5, 35)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-5, 5))
```

[image]

I am trying to set limits within the graph for the labels so that they are always either above 2.5 or under -2.5 and either to the right of 30 or to the left of 0. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/ggrepel.pdf) for `ggrepel`, it doesn't look like you can specify a "label exclusion zone", which is effectively what you are looking for.  The best option would be to use `xlim` and `ylim` to define sections, and then "section off" your data accordingly to create the illusion of a "label exclusion zone".

For this, I broke your data into quadrants:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y, group = z, color = z, label = z)) +
geom_point() +
geom_label_repel(data=subset(data, x<15 & y<0),
    segment.alpha = .5, xlim = c(-5, 0), ylim = c(-5, -2.5)) +
geom_label_repel(data=subset(data, x<15 & y>0),
    segment.alpha = .5, xlim = c(-5, 0), ylim = c(2.5, 5)) +
geom_label_repel(data=subset(data, x>15 & y>0),
    segment.alpha = .5, xlim = c(30, 35), ylim = c(2.5, 5)) +
geom_label_repel(data=subset(data, x>15 & y<0),
    segment.alpha = .5, xlim = c(30, 35), ylim = c(-5, -2.5)) +
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-5, 35)) +
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-5, 5))
```

That gives you this:

[image]

Kind of ew, in my opinion.  To better get the effect you're probably looking for, I would just separate the data into y values above and below the mean, and let `ggrepel` spread them over the x axis as appropriate.  I played with the `force=` argument to "push" them away across the x axis:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y, group = z, color = z, label = z)) +
+     geom_point() +
geom_label_repel(data=subset(data, y<0), force=25,
    segment.alpha = .5, ylim = c(-5, -2.5)) +
geom_label_repel(data=subset(data, y>0), force=25,
    segment.alpha = .5, ylim = c(2.5, 5)) +
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-5, 35)) +
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-5, 5))
```

[image]

You can do the same thing switching axes (split the data according to x value), but I think it will work better here, since the data is spread over a larger x axis area.